# Call custom filtering function on event change in dropdown (dataTable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a custom filtering function and I need to implement it when value is changed in dropdown.

```
function employee_filter(status){
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            // check if current table is part of the allow list
            if ( $.inArray( oSettings.nTable.getAttribute('id'), allowFilter ) == -1 )
            {
               // if not table should be ignored
               return true;
            }

           return aData[8] == status;
        }
);

table.draw();
}
```

HTML :

```
<form class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" style="width: 25%;" id="employee_filter">
    <option value=1>Active Employees</option>
    <option value=0>Ex-Employees</option>
    <option value="">Show All Employees</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

I added event listener to

```
$('select#employee_filter').change( function() { 
    employee_filter($(this).val()); 
} );
```

This is not working, and I am only trying what I can. Please help me with any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this?

```
$(document).on( "change" , "select#employee_filter" , function(){
    employee_filter($(this).val()); 
});
```

also, what does Not work?
does it returns the value?
or does it Not update the table?

Comment: it works when value is changed the first time, and then it returns false and no records are displayed.. I need to refresh the whole page again.

Comment: Once option is selected from the drop-down, the event-listener is continuously calling the employee_filter() with the same parameter value which is selected first. I checked this with alert(val) and it is continuously popping the same value..

Comment: well, then. you call table.draw . can you somehow Clear that table before draw?